# Python in Visual Studio: Erroneous errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, intellisense

I'm not sure if this is an appropriate question for this site, but I'm not sure where else to ask. I've been using MS Visual Studio Professional 2017 to build Python code for a Blender add-on for months now, and have been dealing with this issue since I started. I use the IDE on two PCs (Alienware laptop and custom desktop), and have the same problem on both computers. I don't debug or execute code within VS (although I would if I knew how). I just edit the code, then refresh/test in Blender.

**The problem**

For some reason, I get random intellisense errors while coding (see image below), even when there are no issues. If I delete the error lines, wait a second, then undo the deletion, the errors will go away. So I think this is some type of syncing or refreshing issue. An error occurs while I'm typing, which becomes fixed after I complete the statement, but the error remains indefinitely, until the text is re-parsed.

I included Python capabilities using the Visual Studio installer. I don't believe I have any add-ons enabled. Is anyone familiar with this problem or does anyone know a possible solution?

Snapshot of erroneous errors:

[image: Visual Studio Python Intellisense Errors]

Comment: Hi Robert, any update for this issue? Can the Insert Space option helps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry but I have no direct answer for that, I suggest you can try:

1.Close all VS instance and delete the `.vs` folder in Solution folder, then restart VS after [cleaning the VS cache](https://github.com/Codealike/Codealike-KnowledgeBase/blob/master/clear-visual-studio-component-cache.md).

2.Reset all VS settings like [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/zainnab/2010/07/16/reset-all-your-development-settings/). You can backup your custom settings before reset them.

3.Update vs to latest VS15.9.16. (The Intellisense works well in my machine with VS15.9.16 + python3.6)

Or you may get a similar issue like [this](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/solutions/120578/view.html), change the setting to `Insert Spaces` first, and then do `delete the error lines, wait a second, then undo the deletion` again to remove current errors, then check if you'll get this issue in the further development after that. May it helps :)

Comment: Hey, sorry, I didn't get any notifications of your answer for some reason. I am trying these now. The problem isn't continuous, so I'll report back after testing for a time. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: I've only tried the first step so far (deleting .vs file), but have not encountered this issue since I did that. It may just be good (bad) luck, but I'm hopeful that resolved it. Its possible my .vs file was corrupt, which would explain why it was happening on both PCs. Thank you again

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Visual Studio 2022. (version 17.2.5)

I solved this problem with installing .NET Framework 4.7.2 targeting pack.

Python 3.9 was not completely compatible with .NET Framework 4.8 and my IDE asked me to install this version. I don't know why but it works.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This, somewhat surprisingly, worked for me with VS 17.5.4, whereas the accepted answer did not.  I installed the .NET Framework 4.7.2 Developer pack from [this link](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet-framework/thank-you/net472-developer-pack-offline-installer) and after that Python started working properly in the VS IDE.